# How to Set or retrieve old Path image when we not update the image in the form multiple images in Codeigniter 2.2.6

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have edit form in codeigniter in that form i have 15 more image file while i update the image it updating in database but even am not update the images in the form it goes and save as null or empty path .But i need solution for that when am not update all 15 files should retrive the same old image path which it is stored in database.Please Could you guys give better solution for this.

**My Edit Form**

controller:

```
    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    {   
        if($_FILES['file']['name']!='') 
        {
            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $file_name1 = "upload_".$this->get_random_name()."_".$filename;
            $_SESSION['file_upload']=$file_name1;
            $file ="uploads/images/".$file_name1;

        }   

        if($_FILES['file1']['name']!='') 
        {
            $filename = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
            $file_name2 =       "upload_".$this->get_random_name()."_".$filename;
            $_SESSION['file_upload']=$file_name2;
            $file ="uploads/images/".$file_name2;

        }   
        $query = $this->scener_model->popular_upload($file_name1,$file_name2)
    }
```

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: hi ankit , i need to retrieve same image path when am not given image in the file while i update

Comment: retrive the relevant data from database for the record you are editing. Create a hidden input field and assign your image path into that hidden field. Now when you click on submit simply apply condition to check your input type file is empty or not? if it is empty save the hidden input value in image path field if not do as you are doing.

Comment: hi ankit it not possible to store value in input type file "<input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="file3[]"  accept="image"   value="Value not possible to retrieve here" multiple/ >"

Comment: is there any solution to retrieve database value in file  input type image

Comment: You can't do this. That's why i told you to store your value in a `<input type="hidden" name="something" value="your stored image path here" />`

Comment: hi ankit i need as well input type file also to update  in the edit form to select or browse  the image  format as shown above image

Comment: You can keep them and apply condition to check, as i said in my 2nd comment.

Comment: <div class="col-sm-12">
       <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Upload Image2</label>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
       <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="file3[]"  accept="image"   multiple/ >
         <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="image" name="file3[]"  accept="image"  value="<?php echo $result->iti_image2; ?>"  multiple/ >
       </div>
       </div>

Comment: hi ankit , its not saving old path in database

Comment: is these way correct to get and update image file

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="file3_alt" value="<?php echo $result->iti_image2; ?>" / >` try something like this. input type hidden doesn't accept `accept` & `multiple` attribute. View source code to see either value of your stored file path is printed or not?

Comment: ya ankit output was printed but  at a time i need upload browse the file with in that part if we put type="file" only it browsing ankit please update the things.

Comment: hi ankit could please gave me another solution better than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally guys i found a solution for image updating follwing some tutorials see the link 
"http://www.2my4edge.com/2016/04/multiple-image-upload-with-view-edit.html"

thanks buddies who are give the logic and commenting on my post and thanks alot @ankit singh @Lll

Answer (score 0):

If your  is empty then pass hidden input value or else pass newly uploaded value like this..

```
if(!empty($_FILES()){

//your uploaded value here
} else {
//hidden attribute value
}
```

Comment: hi where it should in view page right   <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="button" id="get_file" value="Grab file">
        <?php 
        $imss= $result->iti_image2; 
        
        ?>
         <?php  foreach($iti_img1 as $im){ ?> 
        <input type="file" id="my_file" name="file3[]"   value="<?php  echo $imss  ?>"  multiple/>
       <div id="customfileupload">Select a file</div>
       <input type="button" class="btn btn info" id="image" name="file3[]"  accept="image"  value="<?php echo  $result->iti_image2; ?>"   multiple/ >
       </div>
       <?php } ?>

Comment: yes in edit form you have to add that particular code.you can use<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $imss ?>' instead of <input type="file" id="my_file" name="file3[]" value="<?php echo $imss ?>" multiple/> for getting image value in else condition for the above code.

Comment: hi lil  could please see above code i post in answer

Comment: Hello you have to write that condition in controller not in view

Comment: kk fine let me try yar

Comment: hi lil ll for else condition how should i print the the values see the code am adding now

Comment: you can print values by using $this->input->post('hidden attribute name here')

Comment: hi lil by using post we only pass the input right how can we print llil please explain clearly yar by using public_model

Comment: instead use get method i.e.,$this->input->get('hidden attribute name here')

Comment: hi lill am still not getting i just post the code if there is any change please change it i gave model also now in code

Comment: my pleasure buddy @IshwaryaSwaminadhan

Answer (score 0):

if($this->input->post('submit1')){

```
            $titlemain = $this->input->post('title_main');  
            $price = $this->input->post('price');   
            $package = $this->input->post('package');
            $titleinner = $this->input->post('title_inner');    
            $city_package = $this->input->post('city_packge');  

            if(!empty($count =count($_FILES['file1']['name']))){;

         for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++){

            $filename1=$_FILES['file1']['name'][$i];
            //print_r($filename);exit;
            $filetmp=$_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $filetype=$_FILES['file1']['type'][$i];

             $images = $_FILES['file1']['name'];

            $filepath="uploads/images/".$filename1;
            move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
         }  
           $filename1 = implode(',',$images);   

            }
            else{

         $filename1=$this->input->get('iti_image2') ;
            //print_r( $data['newz1']);exit;    
            }
```

my view page:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="button" id="get_file" value="Grab file">
                            <?php 
                            $imss= $result->iti_image2; 

                            ?>

                            <input type="file" id="my_file" name="file3[]"   value="<?php  echo $imss  ?>"  multiple/>
                        <div id="customfileupload">Select a file</div>
                        <input type="hidden" class="btn btn info" id="image" name="iti_image2"  accept="image"  value="<?php echo  $result->iti_image2; ?>"   multiple/ >
                        </div>

                        <script>
                            document.getElementById('get_file').onclick = function() {
                             document.getElementById('my_file').click();
                            };
                                $('input[type=file]').change(function (e) {
                             $('#customfileupload').html($(this).val());
                            });

                      </script>
                        </div>
```

my Model:

```
function itinerary_updte($filename4,$filename5){

    $update_itinerarys  = array(
    'iti_image2'    =>$filename4,   
    'iti_image3'    =>$filename5
```

);

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
```

$result = $this->db->update('sg_itinerary', $update_itinerarys);

return $result;

}